# htaccess hide the url ?u=

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want a change the htaccess rule to hide the url expression from user.i am searching to much on google but not get solution.
my website links like this

http://www.psreducators.com/agent-profile/?u=mark-paul

but i want to like this

http://www.psreducators.com/agent-profile/mark-paul

hide this ?u= from the visiter  or a user

agent-profile is not a directory it is a page name in wordpress  and

next is the user name  mark-paul i want a hide only ?u= in this url

agent-profile show in url but actual page name is template_agent_profile.php

Comment: this is depend on your controller.

Comment: working on wordpress the wordpress htaccess rule define

Answer (score 0):

```
# This file is - if you set up HUGE correctly - not needed.
# But, for fallback reasons (if you don't route your vhost to /public), it will stay here.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*) public/$1 [L]

# Everything from is for browser caching and is totally optional

# Deflate Compression by FileType


<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/atom_xml
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-shockwave-flash
</IfModule>

# Set browser caching to 1 month
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_headers.c>
 <filesmatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesmatch>
 <filesmatch "\\.(css)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
 </filesmatch>
 <filesmatch "\\.(js)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
 </filesmatch>
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: i can't unerstand this ode 
can you give siple rewrite rule for my given url ?

Comment: just you can download mvc framework( like MVC anax ) from github.Then you can found solution of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have a folder structure like this:

```
root directory
    dkeknth
        index.php
    agent-profile
        index.php
    derrjjfv
        index.php
    ....
```

if this is the case, you can put a .htaccess file in each folder, where you want to prettify the url and put these lines in .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]+)$ index.php?u=$1 [QSA]
```

In index.php file you can get the value like

```
if(isset($_GET['u'])){
    /*what you want to do*/
}
```

Where you have url like ...index.php?id=1; just replace the `u` with `id`
Now you can access the urls like

http://www.psreducators.com/agent-profile/mark-paul

http://www.psreducators.com/dkeknth/1

http://www.psreducators.com/derrjjfv/1

...

you can also place a single .htaccess file in root directory like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]+)/agent-profile$ agent-profile/index.php?u=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]+)/dkeknth$ dkeknth/index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]+)/derrjjfv$ derrjjfv/index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
...
```

Comment: agent-profile is not a directory it is a page name in wordpress  and next is the user name  mark-paul

Comment: i want a hide only ?u= in this url

Comment: agent-profile show in url but actual page name is template_agent_profile.php

Comment: according to this page https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess you can either use the permalink option or modify the `.htaccess` file. you can try to add the rules in that `.htaccess` file like `RewriteRule ^([a-f0-9]+)/agent-profile$ template_agent_profile.php?u=$1 [QSA]`

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /agent-profile/\?u=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /agent-profile/%1 [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^agent-profile/([^/]+)/?$ /agent-profile/?u=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: What is not workin? do you have a folder named agent-profile ? is this htaccess in that folder?